# Count and sum, counted and summed values

Tags: postgresql, performance, optimization, query-performance

I know the title is a bit mysterious. I just would like to ask how I can optimize this query to work better

I have orders and order_items. Every order_items has order_id from "orders" table so that same order_id can be in various order_items since in and order someone can purchase more than one order_item

I reached my goal with this query. But I think it could have been written better, more optimized.

My goal is to find distinct number of order_ids and total amount of all order_items associated with these order_ids

```
SELECT
  COUNT(*)       AS total_orders,
  SUM(total_invoice_amount) AS total_amount
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      SUM(invoice_amount) AS total_invoice_amount
    FROM
      order_items a
    GROUP BY
      order_id
  ) b;
```

Comment: Please tag your DBMS, you have tagged this question as `mysql` and `postgres`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My goal is to find **distinct number of order_ids** and **total amount** of all order_items associated with these order_ids

You can get same result using a single query:

```
SELECT
  COUNT(DISTINCT order_id) AS total_orders, 
  SUM(invoice_amount) AS total_invoice_amount
FROM
  order_items;
```

Comment: Rather than writing my goal, I could have written the query lol. Thanks :)

Comment: The query is equivalent only if `order_id` is not nullable but that's a fair assumption I think. +1

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ:NULL values are considered equal by `DISTINCT` and `GROUP BY`, so the result is identical. But I am not sure this is faster than the original query of the OP, because `count(DISTINCT ...)` is probably just as expensive as the subquery in the original.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter NULL values are indeed considered equal by DISTINCT and GROUP BY. But McNets query (if there were nulls in `order_id`) won't count them because `COUNT( order_id)` won't (with ether DISTINCT in it or not). `with o (order_id) as (values (null), (null)) select count(*) from (select order_id from o group by order_id) g ;`:  gives `1`, while `with o (order_id) as (values (null), (null)) select count(distinct order_id) from o ;` gives `0`.

Comment: You are right, McNets' count would be *off by one*, I missed that.